# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined" in Select2 Custom Search callback

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Working on Select custom search and got this JavaScript error, can any one explain why its coming?

Just created one select2 with default custom callback search function.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
        matcher: function(term, text) {
          console.log(term, text);
          return text;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select  class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width:300px">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well you do not return from the matcher...

Comment: matcher attribute is looking for `function1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to return from matcher, its looking for some return value, I have already edited question.

```
return text;
```